# Why is my 'mass' value being added to every list in my grid array in Python Rhino?

Tags: python

I am trying to code a floorplan with Python in rhino. I started out with a very simple task of separating the plan into 'mass' and 'space'. I am trying to generate an array in an array which is representative of a grid. Now, my problem is that I get a weird output in the following code:

```
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs
import Rhino.Geometry as rg
import scriptcontext
import System.Drawing as sd

grid_plane = [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]

grid_plane[0][0] = 'mass'

print grid_plane

grid_x = []
grid_y_and_x = []

for d in range(3):
grid_x.append(0)

print grid_x

for d in range(3):
grid_y_and_x.append(grid_x)

print grid_y_and_x

grid_y_and_x[0][0] = 'mass'

print grid_y_and_x
```

The outputs I get are as follows:

```
[['mass', 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
[0, 0, 0]
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
[['mass', 0, 0], ['mass', 0, 0], ['mass', 0, 0]]
```

I do not understand why mass is added in every list as I only want to add it in the fist list at the first instance.

I was expecting the output to be: `[['mass', 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]` for the second part.

but it is: `[['mass', 0, 0], ['mass', 0, 0], ['mass', 0, 0]]`

Comment: You added the list `grid_x` into your `grid_y_and_x` three times. So instead of containing three lists, `grid_y_and_x` contains one list three times.

Comment: @khelwood thanks for the answer, that makes sense. I thought because I am only changing the list afterwards it is not a problem...but apparently it is. Do you know how I could fix this easily or do I need a completely other approach to generatin the Matrix?

Comment: See [the linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) for ways to create nested lists.